# Ifelse logical statement

Tags: r, if-statement, knitr, kable

I'm just starting to learn ifelse statements in functions. Here's a simplified example:

```
library(knitr)

Tab <- iris

my_kable <- function(x, html = TRUE) {
  if(html) {  # any expression here in parentheses is evaluated before it's passed on to the if statement
    kable(x, kable_input = "html")
  } else {
    kable(x, kable_input = "latex")
  }
}

my_kable(Tab, html = FALSE)
```

The issue is in R Markdown, whether I put "html = FALSE" or "html = TRUE" I get the same result (an HTML table). I know I'm missing something very simple...

### UPDATE

My fault! I was trying to an option that doesn't exist in knitr. This works:

```
  if(html) {
    kable(x, format = "html")
  } else {
    kable(x, format = "latex")
  }
```

Comment: there is no argument named `kable_input` to `knitr::kable`. Shouldn't you be using `format = "html" | format = "latex"`?

Comment: You're using a named argument called `kable_input`. `kable` doesn't have such an argument, [looking at the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/knitr/versions/1.19/topics/kable), I think you mean to be using the second argument called `format`. So, you can either make it unnamed and leave it second, or (better choice) you can use `format = ` instead of `kable_input = `

Comment: You both are exactly right - I don't know how I got the wrong option in there. Thank you!